# Grid template not working for Chrome or Mozilla on Mac

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, css-grid

I've made a grid template with properties of grid-template and columns and rows. But when I try to open it with Chrome or Mozilla on Mac it stay with one columns.. and not with the layout that I've made.

What I'm doing wrong?

```css
.grid {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 43% 57%;
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row: 1;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.col-2 { 
  grid-column:2;  
  grid-row: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.col-3 { 
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-1">
    Column 1 - Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    Column 2 - Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    Column 1 and 2 - Row 2
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: How do you expect your grid to look with that code, post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to put your grid class inside style tag in head. It worked for me.